# unidentified 1970's children's sci-fi magazine

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a scifi/activity mag that I read when I was a kid in the mid-70s. There was a serial that spanned several issues sometime around '76-'77 called "Invasion of the Strange Ones".  The story turned out to be a metaphor for the European settlement of North America and the subsequent displacement of the natives who were already here. I remember one issue had a recipe for peanut-butter fudge. Another showed how to make an owl picture made of peanut hulls. I cannot remember the name of this magazine or find anything on the 'net that sounds familiar. It was probably a magazine offered in the Reader's Digest sweepstakes of the time. Anyone remember it?

Comment: [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/) doesn't find anything called “Invasion of the Strange Ones”. Does [Murray Leinster's *Strange Invasion*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?612369) or [Michael Kandel's *Strange Invasion*](http://www.bewilderingstories.com/issue80/) ring a bell? None were published in the right time frame though.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be [Children's Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Digest) ?  They seem to have had some Science Fiction stories, but maybe no crafts, it's hard to tell.  Also it seems to have had alot of Tin Tin stories during the time period you specified.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's Child Craft Magazine.  At least I think that's what it was called.  I would love to find an archive of issues or stories.  The 2 I remember most are one about a people having to jump a chasm to go into a new year, and the other was actually about a boy who went to school at home through his tv.  I'd love to find that one because I cyber school my kids!